# elastalert-create-index Unknown mimetype error

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

While attempting to create index with Elastalert using command `elastalert-create-index` for a basic-auth secured instance using **port:5601** ,it fails with error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.SerializationError: Unknown mimetype, unable to deserialize: text/html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the default port to use for the authenticantication is where **Kibana** is running on port `9200`